# JPanel of larger size than the Scrollpane

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, preferredsize

I have implemented a dialog in which I add a number of checkboxes in a JPanel that also has a scroll bar. The number of check boxes isn't fixed for each run of my program but I know it before I create the dialog.

Unfortunately when I have a large number of checkboxes to add the dialog looks like this:

[image]

My code is:

```
        JPanel listPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(files.size() + 2, 1));

        for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {
            listPanel.add(files.get(i));
        }

        listPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 1400));
        JScrollPane sp =
                new JScrollPane(listPanel, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
                        JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        sp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 200));

        mainPanel.add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainPanel.add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.EAST);

        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        getContentPane().add(mainPanel);

        pack();
        setResizable(false);
```

How can I just set the size of the Panel inside the Scrollpane to a larger size without affecting the frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avoid using `setPreferredSize`, let the layout managers decide the sizes they actually need...

**Updated with example**

The `JViewport` of the scroll pane is using the preferred size of the `listPane` to determine how much viewable space it needs, which is a lot...

In order to overcome this, you need to provide a better hint to the view port as to the viewable size your component would actually like to be.  The `preferredSize` of the component isn't going to work here, you need to supply `preferredScrollableViewportSize` from the `Scrollable` interface

[image]

```
public class BadList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new BadList();
    }

    public BadList() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {

            List<String> files = new ArrayList<>(2000);
            for (int index = 0; index < 2000; index++) {
                files.add(Integer.toString(index));
            }

            ListPane listPanel = new ListPane();
            listPanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            for (String file : files) {
                listPanel.add(new JCheckBox(file), gbc);
            }

            JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(listPanel);

            JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            buttonPane.add(new JButton("Select All"), gbc);
            buttonPane.add(new JButton("Deselect All"), gbc);
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            buttonPane.add(new JPanel(), gbc);

            mainPanel.add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            mainPanel.add(buttonPane, BorderLayout.EAST);

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            add(mainPanel);
        }
    }

    public class ListPane extends JPanel implements Scrollable {

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
            return 128;
        }

        @Override
        public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visibleRect, int orientation, int direction) {
            return 128;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight() {
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

nb- I've used some arbitrary magic numbers in this example, you're going to what to provide more realistic values for your need

Comment: It is not working. If I don't use the PreferredSize on ScrollPane then all the items will be displayed with no scroll bar at all. And there is no difference if I use PreferredSize to the JPanel or not. The result is the same.

Answer (score 3):

- `JPanel` has implemented `FlowLayout`,
- `FlowLayout` accepting only `PreferredSize`, then your `JScrollPane` is correctly layed
- use `JTable` (put there `Boolean value`, representing `JCheckBox`) instead of add childs to the `JPanel` (non_natural scrolling, have to change `scroll increment`)
- `listPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 1400));` isn't nice `Dimmension`, comment this code line, lets that for `pack()`
- for this job (code posted here) I'd be put `JScrollPane` and `buttonPane` to the `JFrame` directly, instead of usage `mainPanel()`, otherwise post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)